# Use tf.roll with increasing shift values and stack

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization, linear-algebra

I've got the following situation.
I have a list of `i` coordinates `(x, y, z)` and have to compute all triples inside a cutoff sphere, such that `r_ij` and `r_ik` are smaller than a cutoff value.
Therefore I am computing a matrix `r_ij` that contains all distances.
To compute the triples my idea is, to construct a `r_ijk` matrix.

I've done this with a loop over the number of elements `i` as

```
import tensorflow as tf

r_ij = tf.reshape(tf.range(4*4), (4, 4))
r_ijk = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    r_ijk.append(tf.roll(r_ij, shift=-i, axis=1))
tf.stack(r_ijk)
```

I want to improve this code because of two issues.
Primarly because I assume, that it could be fully vectorized.
But also to use this in my model, I need to alter it:

```
@tf.function
def get_triplets(full_r_ij, r_cut):
    r_ij = tf.norm(full_r_ij, axis=-1)  # Shape of full_r_ij is (n_timesteps, n_atoms, n_atoms, 3)
    n_atoms = tf.shape(r_ij)[1]
    r_ijk = r_ij[None]

    for atom in range(1, n_atoms):
        tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(
                        shape_invariants=[(r_ijk, tf.TensorShape([None, None, None, None]))]
                    )
        tmp = tf.roll(r_ij, shift=-atom, axis=2)
        r_ijk = tf.concat([r_ijk, tmp[None]], axis=0)  # shape is (n_atoms, n_timesteps, n_atoms, n_atoms)
    r_ijk = tf.transpose(r_ijk, perm=(1, 0, 2, 3))

    r_ijk = tf.where(r_ijk == 0, tf.ones_like(r_ijk) * r_cut, r_ijk)
    intermediate_indices = tf.where(
        tf.math.logical_and(r_ijk[:, 0, None] == 3.0, r_ijk[:, 1:] == 3.0)
    )

    n_atoms = tf.cast(n_atoms, dtype=tf.int64)

    t, n, i, j = tf.unstack(intermediate_indices, axis=1)
    k = j + n + 1
    k = tf.where(k >= n_atoms, k - n_atoms, k)
    triples = tf.stack([t, i, j, k], axis=1)

    return triples
```

and use `tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options` because I am kind of looping over the r_ij tensor.
Is there a way to improve the first code example (or the second as well)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested two further implementations using `tf.vectorized_mad` and `tf.map_fn` which both performed worse than the initial function I wrote. All tests were performed with `r_ij = tf.random.normal((32, 150, 150))`

```
@tf.function
def roll_loop(r_ij, n_atoms):
    r_ijk = r_ij[None]
    for atom in range(1, n_atoms):
        tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(
                        shape_invariants=[(r_ijk, tf.TensorShape([None, None, None, None]))]
                    )
        tmp = tf.roll(r_ij, shift=-atom, axis=2)
        r_ijk = tf.concat([r_ijk, tmp[None]], axis=0)  # shape is (n_atoms, n_timesteps, n_atoms, n_atoms)
    return r_ijk
```

It took `129 ms ± 1.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

```
@tf.function
def roll_vect(r_ij, n_atoms):
    r_ijk = tf.repeat(r_ij[None], repeats=n_atoms, axis=0)
    def roll(args):
        x, shift = args
        return tf.roll(x, shift=shift, axis=2)
    return tf.vectorized_map(roll, [r_ijk, tf.range(n_atoms)])
```

It took `225 ms ± 15.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

```
@tf.function
def roll_map(r_ij, n_atoms):
    r_ijk = tf.repeat(r_ij[None], repeats=n_atoms, axis=0)
    def roll(args):
        x, shift = args
        return tf.roll(x, shift=shift, axis=2)
    return tf.map_fn(roll, (r_ijk, tf.range(n_atoms)), fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
```

It took `327 ms ± 18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

So it seems like going for `tf.function` with python for loop is fastest (so far). All functions were compiled before testing.

EDIT:
Using `tf.TensorArray` seems to be the best way for this task.
I tested it with a few different inputs and it performs as good or even a little better, than `tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options`

```
@tf.function
def roll_loop(r_ij, n_atoms):
    r_ijk = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=n_atoms)
    for atom in range(0, n_atoms):
        tmp = tf.roll(r_ij, shift=-atom, axis=2)
        r_ijk = r_ijk.write(atom, tmp)
    return r_ijk.stack()
```

It took `128 ms ± 1.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`